# Is there more than one registered motor vehicle for every adult in the US?

Tags: united-states, road-vehicles, statistics, population

According to the [US Census Bureau](https://www.census.gov/data/tables/time-series/demo/popest/2010s-national-detail.html#par_textimage_1537638156)'s [table](http://factfinder.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/PEP/2018/PEPSYASEXN?#) of estimated population as of July 1 each year, there were 268.3M people 14 years of age or older, including 260.1M people 16 years of age or older, including 251.6M people 18 years of age or older, as of 2017.

According to [Statista](https://www.statista.com/statistics/183505/number-of-vehicles-in-the-united-states-since-1990/), there were 272.5M registered motor vehicles in the US as of the same year, the latest for which data is available.  (Statista's source for that number is hidden behind a $588/yr paywall).

There are plenty of people who cannot drive, e.g. due to a disability such as blindness which prevents them from doing so.  [Census bureau numbers](https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/tableservices/jsf/pages/productview.xhtml?pid=ACS_17_1YR_S1810&prodType=table) for 2017 list 7.6M with a vision difficulty, including .6M under 18 years old. The Census Bureau is the first source referred to on the National Federation for the Blind's [statistics page](https://nfb.org/resources/blindness-statistics).

Some cannot drive due to legal restrictions, such as license suspension, never having gotten a license in the first place, or long-term incarceration.
There are also lots of people who live in urban centers or other places where they don't need to drive, and where it's not cost-effective to do so.  There are plenty of others who would like to drive and for whom it may even be cost-effective, but who lack the capital/credit/capacity to afford a motor vehicle (especially once including insurance, maintenance, and fuel.)  Some families also have a single (or small number of) vehicle(s) shared among a larger number of drivers.

Despite these factors, is there really more than one registered motor vehicle per eligible person, on average, in the US?  If so, and if you'll excuse the pun, what main factors drive that statistical outcome?

Comment: you don't need to be an adult to drive in the US.  14 years old in South Dakota. https://dps.sd.gov/driver-licensing/south-dakota-licensing-information

Comment: This question follows bad form, (imho). You should be advertising the claim and not trying to justify it or source it in the answer. Explain what you're skeptical of, and if you want to give your own problem a shot do so in an answer (you may get two upvotes). Having read the question, I'm still not sure where the claim originated that you're skeptical of or what the exactly claim was?

Comment: @EvanCarroll The original claim, in the title, was by a credible source but not in a linkable or easily citeable form. So, following the [official site advice on how to ask a good question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), I did some search/research and shared that in the question.

Comment: As far as I can see, no one is making a claim to disprove here except you, interpreting data from various sources. If the original claim was by a credible source, you could start by actually telling us who it was.

Comment: Given the large number of people driving a different vehicle for work than private, is this really a surprise? Think delivery vans for example, mobile cranes, crash tenders, etc. etc. etc.. And then there are the considerable fleets belonging to rental companies like Hertz and Avis.

Comment: @jwenting there are also fleets of rental cars that are driven for purposes that include but are not limited to work.  I haven't owned a car in nearly 20 years but I've driven probably several dozen different US-registered vehicles during that time.

Comment: @pipe The claim was made in a private presentation by the leader of a business with a business model that depends in no trivial part on the accuracy of the claim, so there exists a strong incentive for them to get such facts right, and they are still in business. The content was clearly marked confidential, and other parts were more sensitive than this. *Legal* enforceability of that confidential marking is questionable, but I **will** voluntarily respect it and ask the question using publicly available information that I can link to and is from sources that seem at least comparably credible.

Comment: Confidential claims are not notable. That's pretty much the anti-definition of notable.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Which is why I did not cite it, and instead found more citeable sources with notable claims.  Also, I would not say confidentiality is an anti-definition of notable.  Because of the claimant and venue, the claim has significant potential for real-world impact even if not everybody is able to see that connection. That seems to make it notable.  However, to ask here, it is important to find external sources claiming the same result (also consistent with the official site guidance on how to ask a good question) and that is what I did in the post above.

Comment: "Also, I would not say it's an anti-definition. Because of the claimant and venue, the claim has significant potential for real-world impact even if not everybody is able to see that connection." according to you, which is not notable in the eyes of anyone else. Not to say you're lying but you can't just say the most important person in the world made the claim therefore it's notable.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Maybe you should go on Meta and propose some serious revision to ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the first paragraph, because you appear to strongly disagree with it.

Comment: @DavePhD I've added in the 14+ number; the main point is left unchanged. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @WBT **What topics can I ask about here?
Skeptics Stack Exchange is for challenging unreferenced notable claims, pseudoscience and biased results. Skeptics is about applying skepticism — it is for researching the evidence behind claims you encounter. It is not for speculation, philosophical discussions or investigating original claims. [...] If your question is not about a particular explicit claim, or if it is about research-level science, the following sites may be better suited for your needs:**  https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Key "challenging unreferenced notable claims" not about us having to take your word that a claim even exists...

Comment: I'm also not trying to be a jerk here. The question "Is there >1 registered motor vehicle for every adult in the US?" would be a great question for [opendata.se]

Comment: **"It is for researching the evidence behind claims you encounter."** I encountered a particular explicit and unreferenced claim, which I found to be notable based on claimant & context. I wished to apply a skeptical view of that, searched for more citeable and reliable sources, and shared results of that search as instructed in "how to ask." However, those numbers from those sources still leave room for skepticism about the claim or at least make me wonder what potentially important factors aren't being considered in why the claim seems true and/or surprising. You seem to say it's unwelcome.

Comment: Some speculation on "what main factors drive that statistical outcome?". A. Vehicles are owned by businesses: taxicabs, branded vehicles used by salesmen, repairmen, handymen, even small deliveries (e.g. flowers). B. People who own more than one car: convertible or motorcycle for fun, truck for going to the farm, etc.

Comment: Commercial vehicles - trucks, company-owned delivery vehicles, taxicabs, buses, farm vehicles, rental vehicles..... there's a lot out there that are not for individual use.

Answer (score 12):

The United States Department of Transportation, [Bureau of Transportation Statistics (BTS) reports](https://www.bts.gov/content/number-us-aircraft-vehicles-vessels-and-other-conveyances) that there are 272,480,899 vehicles that are registered for for highway use [as of 2017](https://www.bts.gov/sites/bts.dot.gov/files/table_01_11_053019.xlsx). An additional 63,759 mass transit buses are also registered. Given a population estimate of 327,167,434 [as of July 1, 2018](https://www.census.gov/quickfacts/fact/table/US/PST045218) of which 22.4% are below the age of 18, that gives a population of about 253,881,929.

That makes the claim to be **plausible** with about 1.07 registered highway vehicles in the United States per every resident 18 years or older, with a nominal increase if mass transit vehicles are included.

Comment: There are also a number of farm vehicles (pickup trucks, other trucks exclusively used for farming purposes) and other vehicles that might not be licensed for public road that can be included.

Comment: What's included in this count you've given? Among the cars, vans, and trucks that people vernacularly call "vehicles", American DMVs also demand registration for boats, trailers, RVs, ATVs, snowmobiles, mopeds over 49cc, trailbikes if you want to legally ride on forestry roads, and many other wheeled things that most people wouldn't intuitively call "vehicles".

Comment: @ventsyv and not just farm vehicles but other industries as well, like airport vehicles, many military vehicles, large factory complexes often have vehicles for use on premises only

Comment: @fredsbend Vehicles registered for highway use means that they meet the legal for use on public highways (i.e., trucks, cars, and motorcycles). Other than RVs (which are technically classified as trucks in most cases) most of the others are either not highway legal or cannot move under their own power. Since legal to drive on a highway is a pretty high barrier, boarding things to all other forms of motor vehicles is just going to run up ratio which isn't strictly needed to address the claim.

Comment: @rjzii I was worried they were already being included. Thanks.

Comment: There are 4 cars next door and only two people old enough to drive.  I also know a woman with three cars.

Comment: Dumb question, but registered motor vehicles don't include dealership lots and such?

Comment: @AdamUraynar Yes.